# minLength in tag-it autocomplete tagging

Tags: web-applications, autocomplete, tagging, tag-it

Is there a way to support minLength (start suggestions only after minLength characters have been entered) in [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) ?

Also, can I handle the css of the suggestion box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minLength support has been added to this plugin now. I have styled it by looking at the css classes of the elements it creates.